# `tar` with `find` with removing original file extension

Tags: shell, find, tar, command

I want to create `tb2` files from bunch of text files like this.
`tar cfj $(basename ./2014_04_09.txt .txt).tb2 $(basename ./2014_04_09.txt)`

With this command I can create a archive file `2014_04_09.tb2` that doesn't contain a directory.

But when the command is applied with `-exec` option of `find` like this,

`find . -name "*.txt" -exec tar cfj $(basename "{}" .txt).tb2 $(basename "{}") \;`

This command create archive files with original extension (`2014_04_09.txt.tb2`) and with a directory inside the archive.

How can I use `tar` command with `find` like when be applied only a single file.

Comment: Why create one archive per file? For a single file, you are better to just compress it with `bzip2` (or `gzip`) rather than create an unnecessary archive which is mean for multiple files.

Comment: I only knew `bzip2` and `gzip` command with `tar`. Of course I'll use if I can simply compress a file by `bzip2`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `-exec` a shell command instead:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'tar cfj $(basename "{}" .txt).tb2 "{}"' -- {} \;
```

Moreover, note that your `find` command is *finding* the files at all levels.  As such, using `basename` to pass the list of files wouldn't work if the files do not exist in the current directory.

To elaborate,

```
tar cfj foo.tb2 foo.txt
```

would result into errors if `foo.txt` doesn't exist in the current directory.  As such, you need to pass the path to `foo.txt`.